# Can`t compile accent mark in my Maven Project - IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Few days ago, I have been gotten problems when I use accent marks in my code.

Code:

```
System.out.println("Trámite");
```

aparece en la consola:

```
Tr$amite
```

I am using "$" because I don't find another way to paste the special character that appears.

Just to comment, I am using IntelliJ Idea to code.

Anyone have a configuration to fix this issue that I am facing?

Comment: what file encoding do you use?

Comment: file encoding? I am not sure about that... the default.I think so.

Comment: File -> Settings ... Search for File Encodings (should be under Editor) ... in doubt change it to 'UTF-8' and try again. You can change the encoding of existing files there as well.

Comment: I changed it to UTF-8, but it's the same. doesn't print well the words with acents marks like "Trámite". =(

Comment: can you try running `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 <yourClassname>`

Comment: nothing, it's the same.

Comment: Hmm ... I have no other idea and I can't reproduce this issue. Since itntellij-14 is quite old, updating might help ...

Comment: What do you see if compile and run by Maven from command line?

Comment: Could be a limitation of the terminal used or the font. Can you type the problematic character in your terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely related to the file encoding you are using.
Try to change it to 'utf-8' and see if that solves your problem.

Here a blogpost with some pictures on where to find the proper setting.
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you specified the UTF-8 encoding for project and for this file in Settings(Preferences) | Editor | **File Encodings** settings.

Also to make sure java compiler uses it you can add `-encoding UTF-8` in Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Java Compiler | Javac Options | **Additional command line parameters**.